# Different File/Request size limit in in spring boot application for multipart APIs

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, microservices, multipartform-data

I have set file size below config properties and It's applicable to all multipart APIs. My requirement is to allow a specific API to upload large file size which I don't want to set on global label. Is there any way that I can specify different file and request size limit on different APIs?

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
```